# Why does VeraCrypt not work on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: veracrypt

VeraCrypt was apparently installed during the upgrade to 18.04, but won't open documents.  VeraCrypt icon showed up.  I tried uninstalling, then reinstalling VeraCrypt, and now the icon is gone, and typing 'veracrypt' (or 'sudo veracrypt') in the command-line now returns "command not found"

Comment: Try downloading the package from the official website, extract the package and do a `sudo ./veracrypt-1.22-setup-gui-x64` for the graphical GUI setup. Worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for your response....my problem turned out to be that I had to install the package libexo-1-0 which for some reason was not included in the change to 18.04, at least in my case.

Comment: @DavidGoheen installing libexo-1-0 also fixed the issue for me on 18.10. Thanks!

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 - installing veracrypt_1.23_console_amd64.tar.gz doesn't install the GUI but does install the icon into Gnome dash, so clicking the icon does nothing. I did install libexo-1-0 as suggested above and maybe that's a dependency too, but first do what Abel Tom said above to get the GUI installed and then see if any other actions are necessary.